# Stacked features on same layer, can't bring on foreground

Tags: openlayers

So I have multiple features on the exact same coordinates (which happen to be 0,0 but it is irrelevant I believe)

I run a routine that does something like:

```
clientVectorSource.forEachFeature(function(item) {

                        if (item.get('id') == 1233){
                            /* I tried this part
                            var tempItem=item;
                            clientVectorSource.removeFeature(item);
                            clientVectorSource.addFeature(tempItem);
                            */
                            map.getView().setCenter(item.getGeometry().getCoordinates());
                            selectedFeature=item;
                            if (map.getView().getZoom() < 15)
                                map.getView().setZoom(15);
                        }
                    });
```

selectedFeature is a global variable not relevant to my problem.

The problem is that the "item" is sometimes stacked below the rest of the features due to how it happened to be rendered at the time of execution. I want to bring it on the foreground, but I can't.

I know it could possibly be solved by changing layers on the feature and then changing zIndex to the entire layer but I don't want to resort to that since it is not a very elegant solution and can possibly lead to problems in the future.

I also tried changing the style of "item" to the following and it didn't work:

```
var iconStyleNew = new ol.style.Style({
                    image: new ol.style.Icon( /** @type {olx.style.IconOptions} */ ({
                        anchor: [0.5, 30],

                        anchorXUnits: 'fraction',
                        anchorYUnits: 'pixels',
                        src: 'data/iconMarker.png'
                    })), 
                    zIndex : 999

                });
```

Answer (score 1):

you can take it from the featureSource and push it again so that it goes first:

```
    var tmp=item.clone();
    clientVectorSource.removeFeature(item);
    clientVectorSource.addFeature(tmp);
    clientVectorSource.changed();
```

now your item will be pushed up in the display

Note: order of display depends on the property closure_uid_xxxxx of the feature

Comment: This is what I already tried but it didn't work for some reason.

Comment: I did a clone() for the item, not copy it directly, I was in the same situation before and that's what solved it

Comment: Yes I did a clone, and it still didn't work.

Comment: maybe you should add a break to your code, if it finds the desired item it will modify the order in your vector source so there is no need to keep looping in it

Comment: Yes I already add a return statement. I am now debugging it but I don't see any property closure_uid on console

Comment: that property can be found if you are using ol-debug.js, I don't think it will appear in ol.js, can you make a jsFiddle or a codepen for it ? check the edit

Comment: Sorry for the delay, been really busy, will upload the jsFiddle today or tomorrow